# Inspecting foreign C-Objects to see attributes & members

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

Is there a way to have something like **dir** or **__dict__** for objects coming from a C-Library? In my case, there's a simulation library written in C with a Python wrapper. For instance, one object called CLexWCoordinate is available to me, but dir & dict both are empty.

```
t1 = CLexWCoordinate(0,0,0)
print(t1.getAppId())

dir(t1) # return => []
t1.__dict__ # gives an AttributeError
# How to find other member functions here for t1?
```

Any idea what would work for such a problem? Is there a way to probe objects like these to know what they can do?

Note: The library wraps [this](https://help.hexagonmi.com/bundle/simx_2020/page/combined_book_simx/template_builder/action/TOC.RADE.Tutorials.xhtml). There's no technical reference that I could find **anywhere**. So a class reference is not available to the best of my knowledge.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The examples on [this page](https://help.hexagonmi.com/bundle/simx_2020/page/combined_book_simx/template_builder/action/TOC.Python.Tutorials.xhtml) might help a little, if you didn't already see it, but the only "something like dir" for objects implemented in C *is* `dir`. If that doesn't turn up anything useful (usually because the object uses a *really* outdated way of handling attribute access), then you're basically screwed.

Comment: You're right! Looks like I'm screwed.

Comment: I would have at least expected methods to show up in `dir`, though. The object could be using a really, *really* weird way of handling method access, or I could be misremembering how `dir` behaved in this kind of situation. Just in case, if you haven't already, try calling `help(t1)`. I don't think it'll turn up anything new, but it might, if I'm misremembering something.

Comment: *** No help on (t1) :'D
Could you share what this topics is called, so that I can read up a bit? Btw it's still Py 2.6 in my universe...

Comment: Ah. Now i see that the C-Class probably doesn't have an implementation for \_\_dir__ magic method... Not sure if it was different in Py2 ...

Comment: Really old Python C API code would essentially implement the C-level equivalent of `__getattribute__` and directly handle every supported attribute name in there. This was completely impossible to introspect without extreme measures like trying to step through the code in GDB. (Also, after taking another look at the old `re` module code for reference, I can confirm that methods would not have shown up in `dir` this way.)

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.6.9/Modules/_sre.c#L2601) an example of what that would have looked like, from the Python 2.6 version of the `re` module. It calls `Py_FindMethod` with an array of `PyMethodDef` structs to handle methods, then manually handles every supported non-method attribute name with a series of `if`s and `strcmp`s.

Comment: Looks like a dead end to me. It'd be far easier to find a way around ...

I'd try and think about the GDB approach, but I dont think its worth the effort. Maybe a workaround would be a better solution.

Thanks a lot for your help!